# If Records exist with Similar Unique Key then show there Sum else Show Record value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of Invoice with different Invoices. Each Invoice has a unique Invoice Number and an amount value. Invoices are of two type. One is of Invoice Type, and the other is of Settled type. If there's a invoice created, the entry in the table will be of invoice type, the amount will be in positive. If the user paid that invoice, another entry with the same invoice number will be entered in the table but with the negative amount because the user has paid that amount.

Now I want to to show the record if there exist any two records with same invoice number, then show the record with calculating the sum of the Amount (which means Adding the Amount of Invoice type record and the settlement type record). And those records which have a unique invoice number (with no settlement record) should be displayed as it is (without sum).

I guess the query will be some what of this kind.., but that's not exactly what I want!

```
Select 
    InvoiceNumber, InvoiceTypeCode, 
    Amount = case when COUNT(InvoiceNumber) > 1
                   then SUM(Amount)
                   else Amount
             end
from 
    Invoice
group by 
    InvoiceNumber, Amount, InvoiceTypeCode
```

Comment: Why don't you *always* display the sum? If there are not two, but only one invoice, that will amount to exactly the same thing, but it makes things easier for you. After all, wasn't the idea behind cancelling out an open invoice's amount with a settled invoice's negative amount (double-entry book-keeping?) precisely that you can always rely on summing up the amounts to get the correct balance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to diffentiate between the cases, if you have a single record then the sum is the same as the value.

You should't group on the amount and type code, then the two records with the same invoice number will be in different groups.

```
select
  InvoiceNumber, Amount = sum(Amount)
from
  Invoice
group by
  InvoiceNumber
```

Comment: Thank you @Guffa. Really it was as straight forward as it looks. I'd just lost my mind and thought that it might be done by 'Case' statement and now i am laughing at my self. Thank you once again! Cheers! :)